# Openshift Origin secure git clone errors

Tags: git, openshift-origin

Giving openshift origin V3 a try with a simple byo runbook setup that sticks closely with the Advanced Installation instructions. However, my builds are having difficulty cloning from any git repository, even public github ones.

HTTPS:

```
F0609 05:01:49.810021       1 builder.go:204] Error: build error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/blongden/phpinfo.git/': Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.
```

SSH:

```
I0609 05:10:41.228300       1 source.go:197] Downloading "git@github.com:blongden/phpinfo.git" ...
F0609 05:10:41.867643       1 builder.go:204] Error: build error: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have no problems cloning the repo manually on my master.

Any wisdom will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are using same public key that you have uploaded to openshift!

Comment: This is openshift origin at openshift.ORG running on-premise, not hosted openshift online at openshift.COM. 

Even then, it is a public repository, so no authentication is required.

Comment: BTW, are you behind a corporate proxy? https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/http_proxies.html#configuring-default-templates-for-proxies. Can you check out the project on the node directly?

Comment: I am not behind a corporate proxy. I can check out the project on the node directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all `searchdomain` entries in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` or `/etc/resolv.conf` file fixed the issue.

This was discovered by testing on a local setup with DHCP addressing instead of a manually assigned IP with the host in my original question, which worked fine, which helped to narrow down the issue to networking differences between both environments.